# Проверить наличие переполнения блока на css

Tags: css, css3

Есть `div` c `overflow:auto`. Нужно в случае наличия у него горизонтального скролла ограничить его высоту `max-height:100vh`, а в случае отсутствия горизонтального скролла, никак её не ограничивать.

Возможно ли сделать такое в современных браузерах, если использовать только css?

В следующем примере проблема со вторым блоком. http://jsfiddle.net/177krpja/1/

```css
.block {
    white-space: pre;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    max-height: 7.5em; /* По вопросу тут 100vh */
    overflow: auto;
    background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">Здесь скролла нет
Здесь скролла нет
Здесь скролла нет</div>
    
<div class="block">Здесь вертикального сколла тоже нет!
Здесь вертикального сколла тоже нет!
Здесь вертикального сколла тоже нет!
Здесь вертикального сколла тоже нет!
Здесь вертикального сколла тоже нет!
Здесь вертикального сколла тоже нет!
Здесь вертикального сколла тоже нет!
Здесь вертикального сколла тоже нет!
Здесь вертикального сколла тоже нет!
Здесь вертикального сколла тоже нет!
Здесь вертикального сколла тоже нет!
Здесь вертикального сколла тоже нет!
Здесь вертикального сколла тоже нет!
Здесь вертикального сколла тоже нет!</div>

<div class="block">Здесь вертикального скролла нет, поскольку max-height не превышен. Здесь вертикального скролла нет, поскольку max-height не превышен. Здесь вертикального скролла нет, поскольку max-height не превышен. Здесь вертикального скролла нет, поскольку max-height не превышен.
Здесь вертикального скролла нет, поскольку max-height не превышен. Здесь вертикального скролла нет, поскольку max-height не превышен. Здесь вертикального скролла нет, поскольку max-height не превышен. Здесь вертикального скролла нет, поскольку max-height не превышен. 
Здесь вертикального скролла нет, поскольку max-height не превышен. Здесь вертикального скролла нет, поскольку max-height не превышен. Здесь вертикального скролла нет, поскольку max-height не превышен. Здесь вертикального скролла нет, поскольку max-height не превышен.</div>

<div class="block">Здесь вертикальный скролл есть, поскольку есть горизонтальный и максимальная высота превышена. Здесь вертикальный скролл есть, поскольку есть горизонтальный и максимальная высота превышена. Здесь вертикальный скролл есть, поскольку есть горизонтальный и максимальная высота превышена. Здесь вертикальный скролл есть, поскольку есть горизонтальный и максимальная высота превышена.
Здесь вертикальный скролл есть, поскольку есть горизонтальный и максимальная высота превышена. Здесь вертикальный скролл есть, поскольку есть горизонтальный и максимальная высота превышена. Здесь вертикальный скролл есть, поскольку есть горизонтальный и максимальная высота превышена. Здесь вертикальный скролл есть, поскольку есть горизонтальный и максимальная высота превышена.
Здесь вертикальный скролл есть, поскольку есть горизонтальный и максимальная высота превышена. Здесь вертикальный скролл есть, поскольку есть горизонтальный и максимальная высота превышена. Здесь вертикальный скролл есть, поскольку есть горизонтальный и максимальная высота превышена. Здесь вертикальный скролл есть, поскольку есть горизонтальный и максимальная высота превышена.
Здесь вертикальный скролл есть, поскольку есть горизонтальный и максимальная высота превышена. Здесь вертикальный скролл есть, поскольку есть горизонтальный и максимальная высота превышена. Здесь вертикальный скролл есть, поскольку есть горизонтальный и максимальная высота превышена. Здесь вертикальный скролл есть, поскольку есть горизонтальный и максимальная высота превышена.
Здесь вертикальный скролл есть, поскольку есть горизонтальный и максимальная высота превышена. Здесь вертикальный скролл есть, поскольку есть горизонтальный и максимальная высота превышена. Здесь вертикальный скролл есть, поскольку есть горизонтальный и максимальная высота превышена. Здесь вертикальный скролл есть, поскольку есть горизонтальный и максимальная высота превышена.
Здесь вертикальный скролл есть, поскольку есть горизонтальный и максимальная высота превышена. Здесь вертикальный скролл есть, поскольку есть горизонтальный и максимальная высота превышена. Здесь вертикальный скролл есть, поскольку есть горизонтальный и максимальная высота превышена. Здесь вертикальный скролл есть, поскольку есть горизонтальный и максимальная высота превышена.
Здесь вертикальный скролл есть, поскольку есть горизонтальный и максимальная высота превышена. Здесь вертикальный скролл есть, поскольку есть горизонтальный и максимальная высота превышена. Здесь вертикальный скролл есть, поскольку есть горизонтальный и максимальная высота превышена. Здесь вертикальный скролл есть, поскольку есть горизонтальный и максимальная высота превышена.
Здесь вертикальный скролл есть, поскольку есть горизонтальный и максимальная высота превышена. Здесь вертикальный скролл есть, поскольку есть горизонтальный и максимальная высота превышена. Здесь вертикальный скролл есть, поскольку есть горизонтальный и максимальная высота превышена. Здесь вертикальный скролл есть, поскольку есть горизонтальный и максимальная высота превышена.
Здесь вертикальный скролл есть, поскольку есть горизонтальный и максимальная высота превышена. Здесь вертикальный скролл есть, поскольку есть горизонтальный и максимальная высота превышена. Здесь вертикальный скролл есть, поскольку есть горизонтальный и максимальная высота превышена. Здесь вертикальный скролл есть, поскольку есть горизонтальный и максимальная высота превышена.
Здесь вертикальный скролл есть, поскольку есть горизонтальный и максимальная высота превышена. Здесь вертикальный скролл есть, поскольку есть горизонтальный и максимальная высота превышена. Здесь вертикальный скролл есть, поскольку есть горизонтальный и максимальная высота превышена. Здесь вертикальный скролл есть, поскольку есть горизонтальный и максимальная высота превышена.
Здесь вертикальный скролл есть, поскольку есть горизонтальный и максимальная высота превышена. Здесь вертикальный скролл есть, поскольку есть горизонтальный и максимальная высота превышена. Здесь вертикальный скролл есть, поскольку есть горизонтальный и максимальная высота превышена. Здесь вертикальный скролл есть, поскольку есть горизонтальный и максимальная высота превышена.
Здесь вертикальный скролл есть, поскольку есть горизонтальный и максимальная высота превышена. Здесь вертикальный скролл есть, поскольку есть горизонтальный и максимальная высота превышена. Здесь вертикальный скролл есть, поскольку есть горизонтальный и максимальная высота превышена. Здесь вертикальный скролл есть, поскольку есть горизонтальный и максимальная высота превышена.
Здесь вертикальный скролл есть, поскольку есть горизонтальный и максимальная высота превышена. Здесь вертикальный скролл есть, поскольку есть горизонтальный и максимальная высота превышена. Здесь вертикальный скролл есть, поскольку есть горизонтальный и максимальная высота превышена. Здесь вертикальный скролл есть, поскольку есть горизонтальный и максимальная высота превышена.
Здесь вертикальный скролл есть, поскольку есть горизонтальный и максимальная высота превышена. Здесь вертикальный скролл есть, поскольку есть горизонтальный и максимальная высота превышена. Здесь вертикальный скролл есть, поскольку есть горизонтальный и максимальная высота превышена. Здесь вертикальный скролл есть, поскольку есть горизонтальный и максимальная высота превышена.
Здесь вертикальный скролл есть, поскольку есть горизонтальный и максимальная высота превышена. Здесь вертикальный скролл есть, поскольку есть горизонтальный и максимальная высота превышена. Здесь вертикальный скролл есть, поскольку есть горизонтальный и максимальная высота превышена. Здесь вертикальный скролл есть, поскольку есть горизонтальный и максимальная высота превышена.
Здесь вертикальный скролл есть, поскольку есть горизонтальный и максимальная высота превышена. Здесь вертикальный скролл есть, поскольку есть горизонтальный и максимальная высота превышена. Здесь вертикальный скролл есть, поскольку есть горизонтальный и максимальная высота превышена. Здесь вертикальный скролл есть, поскольку есть горизонтальный и максимальная высота превышена.</div>
```

---

*Решение с использованием js не требуется, поскольку я сам могу его реализовать.*

*Кроссбраузерность не требуется. Также интересуют варианты, которые должны работать в соответствии со стандартом, но ещё не реализованы браузерами.*

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду под словом ограничивать? По идее указанные 2 свойства уже сделают всё что нужно :) добавят скролл к блоку если высота контента превысит 100vh и не дадут блоку быть больше чем 100 vh

Comment: "добавят скролл к блоку если высота контента превысит 100vh и не дадут блоку быть больше чем 100 vh" - именно так, а надо "в случае отсутствия горизонтального скролла, никак её не ограничивать".

Comment: "Никак не ограничивать" имеет 3 смысла: 1) по высоте контента, 2) по высоте окна браузера, 3) 100500px в высоту или любое другое кастомное значение, которое задаётся вручную. Что нужно вам?

Comment: По высоте контента. { overflow: auto; height: auto; } и if (есть-горизонтальный-скролл) { max-height: 100vh; } else { max-height: none; }

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/177krpja/ Вот пример, 2 блока с одинаковым классом, в одном контента меньше 30vh, в другом больше, блоки имеют ваши первоначальные 2 свойства и подходят под оба условия, для показательности я добавил ещё пару свойств.  Что вас не устраивает в этом?

Comment: У обоих горизонталоного скорлла нет, поэтому первый под условие не подходит - у него тоже (!) не должно быть вертикального скролла. Вот обновлённый пример - сравни поведение с текстом внутри - у второго блока несоответствие: http://jsfiddle.net/177krpja/1/

Comment: Наконец-то до меня дошло, что скролл горизонтальный, просто странное поведение и слова воспринялись неправильно и как было бы логичнее :) вообщем, исходя из моих знаний, это вряд ли получится сделать без скриптов

Comment: Для таких случаев и придумывали LESS

Comment: @Zelta, ваш комментарий совершенно бесполезен, и для сведения, LESS это препроцессор, на выходе всё равно получается CSS и, если задачу можно решить с помощью LESS, то её можно решить и с помощью CSS.

Comment: @Zelta, и как же ты собрался сделать это на less? Тем более, всё что возможно в less возможно в css. Только кода в некоторых случаях меньше может быть.

Comment: @Discord, за что так с метками?

Comment: @Qwertiy Современные браузеры — понятие, для которого не существует формального определения. Абсолютно бессмысленная метка, хуже неё только "программирование". "nojs" — это мета-метка, описывающая предпочтения автора, а не что-то напрямую относящееся к вопросу. Если есть предпочтения, выразите их в вопросе, а не засоряйте метки.

Comment: @Discord, смысл метки "Современные браузеры" я выразил в описании к ней. Вроде кто-то даже утвердил? Более хорошего названия для неё не придумал. Если есть хорошие идеи, можно назвать как-то по другому. "nojs" ясно выражает неуместность ответов с джаваскриптовым кодом. Потому что, как правило, html, css и js идут все в одной связке и если что-то невозможно сделать только при помощи css, то это покрывается скриптами. Если посмотреть внимательнее метки, то при метках html+css очень часто есть ответы для js. Но сделать на js я и сам могу. Эта метка по сути равна другим меткам с языками.

Comment: @Qwertiy Обе метки — мета-метки, то есть описывают *общее свойство* (большой, кислый, круглый), а не *конкретный объект* (планета, лимон, дверь), причём делают это неоднозначно. Мета-метки запрещены. Вообще. Все. Целиком и полностью. Что вам хочется, что вы подразумеваете и далее по списку — значения не имеет абсолютно, потому что такие метки нельзя использовать в принципе. Если у вас остались вопросы, добро пожаловать не Мету.

Comment: @Qwertiy В чате произошла традиционная вещь: администрация принялась рассказывать, какой Сквидвард плохой. (Это после монолога в видео с Хуаном на тытрубе.) Единственным отличием было то, что травлю спровоцировал не Паша, а Николас. Правда, похоже, он внял моим словам в скайпе (хоть и не ответил), поэтому пропали все сообщения, включая его и пашины. Я вышел из чата со словами "Всё, достали", Паша продожил наезды ("ты не умеешь общаться, бла-бла-бла"). Судя по состоянию главной страницы чатов, я забанен, как обычно. Но это уже не имеет значения.